# Read kmz file and show images on map

Tags: iphone, xcode, mapkit, kml, kmz

i read this tutorial [Apple kml viewvwer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KMLViewer/Listings/Classes_KMLViewerViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010046-Classes_KMLViewerViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_8) article. Its helps me to load kml but when i load images too. I create folder name files and write png images in the folder.. in kml file, image refrence are used.. Here is the code

```
self.archive = [ZKDataArchive archiveWithArchivePath:archivePath];
[self.archive inflateAll];
for (int i =0;i < [self.archive.inflatedFiles count]; i++) {

    NSDictionary *fileDict = [self.archive.inflatedFiles objectAtIndex:i]; 
    NSData *fileData = [fileDict objectForKey:ZKFileDataKey];
    NSString *fileName = [fileDict objectForKey:ZKPathKey];
    NSString *ext = [fileName pathExtension];

    NSString* fileToSaveTo;

    if([fileName isEqualToString:@"doc.kml"])
    {

        fileToSaveTo = fileName;
        NSArray* path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString* documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@",documentsDirectory);
        [fileData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,fileToSaveTo] atomically:YES];

    }
    else{
        fileToSaveTo = [fileName substringFromIndex:6];
        NSLog(@"%@",fileToSaveTo);

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        // Get documents folder
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"files"];
        NSLog(@"%@",documentsDirectory);
        [fileData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",dataPath,fileToSaveTo] atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

But i cant see images on the map. Images are safe in document and kml file read perfect... But i want to show images too :(

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on any use of kml in an iPhone app, but I think the issue you're having is likely before that even happens.

If you view the kml/kmz in Google Earth on a desktop, do they both work properly?  You have not stated as such, but my guess would be no.  If it does, then it is a problem in something I can't help with.

My suggestion would be to actually inspect the kmz file references and structure.  The general standard for a kmz file is to have a doc.kml file in the root of the archive and all resources in a 'files' directory in that archive.  Because of this, all references should be *relative* like: `<href>files\image.png</href>`  Many programs that generate kml will use absolute references that work locally, but not when zipped to a kmz or when viewed by anyone else.